# Pandas - Quick way to convert values to 1 and 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe "df":

```
   x
0 -2
1  2
2 -4
3  2
4  9
5 -2
```

I am trying to find a fast way to create a new column df['binary'], where all positive values in df['x'] are input as 1, and negative values in df['x'] are input as 0 in the new df['binary'] column. The real frame is very large so I am trying to do this with speed. Any help appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: If there are any values of 0, what should happen to them?

Comment: they can be 0 in the binary column

Comment: Gee, if only there was a way to...oh, I dunno....`apply` a function to a column. Bah, that's just crazy talk!

Comment: @Jack, do you think the apply method would be faster than the two answers already provided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`assign` + `gt`

```
df.assign(binary=df.x.gt(0) * 1)

   x  binary
0 -2       0
1  2       1
2 -4       0
3  2       1
4  9       1
5 -2       0
```

---

If speed is what your after

```
df['binary'] = (df.x.values > 0).astype(np.uint8)
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason assign was not working, but just using df['binary'] = df.x.gt(0) * 1 did the job.

Comment: @JeffSaltfist `assign` doesn't update the `df`, it creates a new copy with the assigned columns.  It's a stylistic preference for me.  My answer was intended to be elegant.  If you want speed, there is still an additional step you could take in addition to what @mtd provided.

Answer (score 5):

@piRSquared's answer is good -- you can find some ways to speed this up:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: import numpy as np, pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(1000000) - 0.5})
In [3]: %timeit df['binary'] = df['x'].gt(0).astype(np.short)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.74 ms per loop
In [4]: %timeit df['binary'] = df['x'].gt(0).astype(np.short)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.78 ms per loop
```

Is faster for me than:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: import numpy as np, pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(1000000) - 0.5})
In [3]: %timeit df.assign(binary=df.x.gt(0)*1)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.48 ms per loop
In [4]: %timeit df.assign(binary=df.x.gt(0)*1)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.54 ms per loop
```

Comment: 10.6 ms per loop as opposed to 13.1 ms per loop. Also, the other version had a large variance in times. Very nice!